# SQL Windowing function: MAX(date) over Partition BY Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query as:

```
select 
    location_id,
    max(created) over (partition by location_id) as "created"
from 
    device
group by 
    location_id, created
order by 
    location_id
```

This results in max date being repeated against each grp.

> 21    2015-01-26T18:25:00.000Z
>   22    2015-10-18T13:21:32.000Z
>   22    2015-10-18T13:21:32.000Z
>   22    2015-10-18T13:21:32.000Z

Now if I calculate the difference between the dates:

```
select 
    location_id,
    date(created),
    max(date(created)) - min(date(created)) over (partition by location_id) as "created"
from 
    device
group by 
    location_id, created
order by 
    location_id
```

> 21    2015-01-26T00:00:00.000Z    0
>   22    2015-01-26T00:00:00.000Z    0
>   22    2015-03-12T00:00:00.000Z    45
>   22    2015-10-18T00:00:00.000Z    265

Why do I get difference between first record and 2nd and then 3rd? Why not just the difference between max-min repeated through the groups?

Hope I am clear with the question.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second query is parsed like this:

```
select . . .
       (max(date(created)) -
        min(date(created)) over (partition by location_id)
       ) as "created"
. . .
```

That is, the windowing clause is only applied to the `min()`.  I think you intend:

```
select . . .
       (max(date(created) over (partition by location_id) -
        min(date(created)) over (partition by location_id)
       ) as "created"
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query you partition by location - so basically the min and max are considered in context to the individual locations... this might explain, why you have differenet min and max per line.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you are not using the window function for Max in your second query.

Try:

```
max(date(created)) over (partition by location_id) - min(date(created)) over (partition by location_id) as "created"
```

If I am guessing wrong I think it would be helpful if you could provide sample data and example results it will